# Meaning difference between SUMMATION and not in the MIP model

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint

I'm asking you a question because I was confused about MIP while reading the paper.
This paper is about dual crane optimization.
In the MIP model of the paper, equations (7) and (8) are used to model similar situations, but (7) has $\sum_{i \in I} y^2_{ist}$, and (8) has no $\sum_{i \in I} y^2_{ist}$. I don't know why there's this difference.
I think that $y^2_{ist}$ is 1 when $(i, s, t)$ set should be only one case about $i$.
when $(i, s, t)$ is (1, 4, 5), $y^2_{ist}$ is 1 then $(1, s', t')$ $s$ in $S$ not 4, $t$ in $T$ not 5. so, I can't understand above (7), (8) what is difference $\sum_{i \in I} y^2_{ist}$.

(7) means that if the landside crane starts to pick up container i in slot s at time t ($y^2_{ist} = 1$), then it is actually located in slot s throughout the time interval [t, t + p] (loading time). 
(8) means that if the landside crane starts to pick up container i in slot s at time t ($y^2_{ist} = 1$), then it is actually located in slot s throughout the unlodaing time.

[image]

[image]
[article site](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X16301652)

Answer (score 0):

Constr(7) is saying from every slot $s$ if any container (that's why you have summation, whenever you want to work on conditions like *any/atleast*) is picked up, the seaside crane's position $ x_{2t}$ at time $t$ should be at slot $s$ where atleast 1 container is picked up. Otheriwse $x_{2t}$ is free.
Constr(8) is saying for a container $i$ picked up from a slot $s$ (that's why you need to iterate over all slots & container, meaning of for-loop), travel the distance $s_i-s$ in same time $ s_i-s$ excluding pick-up/drop-off ($p$) for the crane's position to be at $s_i$-destination slot for container $i$ if $i$ is picked-up ($y_{ist}^2=1$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I'm really sorry that I can't ask additional questions right away because my reputation is less than 50.
I don't know if you'll see my additional question again, but if there's no Summation in (7), will there be a problem?
In fact, there is confusion because we take Summation for both I and s for z under condition (9).
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZGG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZGG.png)

Comment: One slot say $s$ will have multiple containers $i$. Nowi f you dont use sum in constr(7) then you will end up creating multiple constraints for every container $i$! Summation makes it simple, idea is just to tell the crane to 'Go to the slot from where you(crane) are picking up atleast one container'. So if you use a sum, then even if 1 container is picked up, it will turn $y=1$ and $x$ will point to that slot $s$ from where container is being picked up.

Comment: Constrs (9,10) are for seaside crane. For that I need to understand the operation in depth. But $y^1$ for seaside seems to mean here slot $s$ doesn't matter. So constr (9) tells the seaside crane-'after releasing atleast/whatever number of containers $i$ from whatever number of slots, position yourself at time $t'= t+p$: $x$ at the last slot where you released'. So if seaside is say releasing 1 container at slot 4, another 1 container at slot 5, so after $t+p$ its position will be 4+5=9. Why seaside is programmed like this, for that we need to understand the full logic of operations given.